# Problems reading data into an array list from a file in Java

Tags: java

So this is my first time posting here. I am trying to read data from a file, create multiple objects from that data, and then place the created objects into an ArrayList. But every time I have tried, I just get multiple copies of the same object, instead of different objects. I am at my wits end.

Anyways, here is the code for the method to read the data in from the file. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
public void openShop() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("What is the name of the shop?");
    shopName = keyboard.nextLine();
    setShopFile();
    File openShop = new File(shopFile);
    if (openShop.isFile()){
        Scanner shopData = new Scanner(openShop);
            shopName = shopData.nextLine();
            shopOwner = shopData.nextLine();

            while (shopData.hasNextLine()){
                shopItem.setName(shopData.nextLine());
                shopItem.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(shopData.nextLine()));
                shopItem.setVintage(Boolean.parseBoolean(shopData.nextLine()));
                shopItem.setNumberAvailable(Integer.parseInt(shopData.nextLine()));
                shopItem.setSellerName(shopData.nextLine());
                shopInventory.add(shopItem);

            }
            setNumberOfItems();
    }
    else
        System.out.println("That shop does not exist. Please try to open" +
                          "the shop again.");
    isSaved = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

inside your while loop you should create a new instance of an object. Else it would only end up making modifications to the exisiting instance.

Correct way :

```
while (shopData.hasNextLine()){
   shopItem = new ShopItem(); //This will create a new Object of type ShopItem
   shopItem.setName(shopData.nextLine());
   shopItem.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(shopData.nextLine()));
   shopItem.setVintage(Boolean.parseBoolean(shopData.nextLine()));
   shopItem.setNumberAvailable(Integer.parseInt(shopData.nextLine()));
   shopItem.setSellerName(shopData.nextLine());
   shopInventory.add(shopItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cant see where you're creating the shopItem instance.

But if you're not creating a new ShopItem each time then every time you go around the loop you're just updating the one instance, and then adding it to the shopInventory.

Answer (score 1):

You fill your ArrayList using the very same object. You should create a new instance of `ShopItem`:

```
while (shopData.hasNextLine()){
  ShopItem shopItem = new ShopItem();
  shopItem.setName(shopData.nextLine());
  ...
}
```